# How can I override the autocomplete.js file while developing a module?

Tags: entities, ajax

I want to override the default tags field wherever it is used. After looking through a few files, I figured that I should override drupal/misc/autocomplete.js and the `Drupal.jsAC` object.

Is it correct to override this file, since I only want to work with tags field?
How is it possible to create a module which overrides this file?

Comment: Have you read about [form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and [#autocomplete_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#autocomplete_path)? Any reason they are not sufficient for you?

Comment: Yes, because I need to change HTML structure of auto-completion suggestions `<ul>`.

Comment: If they originate from js, behaviors are way to go. If they came from autocomplete itself, alter hooks are needed. If they are not accessible from neither, Drupal has a design bug (not it's first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all you want to do is achievable by using [form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and [#autocomplete_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#autocomplete_path), you should avoid modifying core's JavaScript files. To address specific field widget, use [hook_field_widget_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7).

If you need to alter what JavaScript is doing, use [corresponding behaviours, as described on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018981/how-to-dynamically-reconfigure-drupals-jquery-based-autocomplete-at-runtime).